# TestCafe not rendering elements with Angular asyncPipe

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Using TestCafe directives using the Angular asyncPipe are not rendered or clickable in the browser for testing:

Example Element -

```
  <a mat-tab-link
    *ngIf="capabilitiesFacade.hasPermissionCapability(VIEW_CALL_DETAILS) | async"
    [disabled]="!(permissionsFacade.hasPermission(VIEW_CALL_DETAILS) | async)" (click)="changeTab('details')"
    [ngClass]="{'tab-focus': currTab === 'details'}">
    DETAILS
  </a>
```

In TestCafe -

```
Selector('.mat-tab-link').withText(' DETAILS '); //Element is not rendered
```

If I remove the `| async` - the element is rendered.

Comment: Hi, is element rendered when you open a test page in a browser without TestCafe?

Comment: Yes. The same local server running without TestCafe renders the element. The tab is rendered and clickable. When TestCafe test gets to the view that element is missing.

Comment: Please upload a reproducible example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular).